# Cannot install RoboVM plugin on IntelliJ Idea

Tags: ios, intellij-idea, libgdx, robovm, mobivm

IntelliJ Idea fails when trying to install RoboVM plugin. I found these errors in the log:

> Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: download.robovm.org

It must be a problem of the server, because I cannot access with an Internet browser either:

> download.robovm.org’s server IP address could not be found

I know it maybe a temporal issue, but just in case, do you know if the project has been discontinued or something alike?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**RoboVM is no more**, Probably his server, `IP address` is not active/working.

Try [MobiDevelop](http://robovm.mobidevelop.com/), a fork of RoboVM. This fork is based on the last open-source version of RoboVM.

Plugins for IntelliJ IDEA/Android Studio

- [IntelliJ IDEA plugin snapshot builds](http://robovm.mobidevelop.com/downloads/snapshots/idea)
- [IntelliJ IDEA plugin release builds](http://robovm.mobidevelop.com/downloads/releases/idea)

Comment: I'll give these a try. Thanks!